# Can I use single EntityAdapter for a few instance of the same EntityState?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

I have a one EntityStates of the same model assigned to a few properties in the single state. Can I manipulate all of them using a single adapter? They have the same initial state but will contain values with various status.

```
interface myState {
   entity1: EntityState,
   entity2: EntityState
   entity3: EntityState
}

export interface EntityState extends EntityState<MyModel> {}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<MyModel> = createEntityAdapter<MyModel>();

export const myInitialState: EntityState = adapter.getInitialState({
  loaded: false
});

export const initialState = {
   entity1: myInitialState,
   entity2: myInitialState
   entity3: myInitialState 
}
```

and then I would like to is with a single entity instance like that

```
state{
...state
entity1: adapter.addMany(payload {
  ...state.entity1
  loaded: true
 )
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can do it, since adapter is just a function, that returns new state. But I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve. Usually the same entities are stored and  managed by the same reducer.

Comment: They have the same model but hold entities with different status, an I prefer to hold them in separate property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work. 
The adapter's function is pure, it takes some state and a "payload" and will returns a new updated state.

The snippet you posted is valid.